# Why does my powershell script run with "pwsh" but doesn't with "sudo pwsh"?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I'm still somewhat new to Ubuntu / Linux so please bear with me if I'm not using correct terminology. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 but I use Putty to perform everything via the terminal.

I'm using a collection of shell scripts (`.sh` files) and PowerShell scripts (`.ps1` files) to retrieve Azure metric data. I had it setup along with `crontab` to run every 15 minutes and it was working for about a month with no problems. I'm using PowerShell 7.4.0 which is installed from snap/snapd.

The scripts no longer work with crontab. Specifically, it doesn't retrieve the data from Azure anymore. I know this isn't an Azure issue because I can run the script fine manually in the command line using `pwsh /full/path/xyz.sh <parameter>`. However, when I try to run the script using `sudo` before `pwsh`, I get two lines of errors:

Stack overflow. 
Aborted

I'm assuming the two issues are related but I've tried changing permissions, removing and re-adding PowerShell, changing the file owners/groups, changing what user calls the script in `crontab`, and a few other things I found on other forums. The only error log I was able to find related to the script was in `/var/log/apport.log` which stated:

```
executable does not belong to a package, ignoring
```

Hopefully this is enough information but I can provide more if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that `crontab` couldn't find `pwsh` so I placed the entire path `/snap/bin/pwsh` instead of just `pwsh` in the shell script file to run the `.ps1` file and all works again.